# CSS Containing a Background Image in a DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of stuck here trying to figure out how to keep a background image from sagging below it's DIV. I've had to resort to some rather unsavory tactics.

```
.animation span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    background-size: cover cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

...

<body>
  <div id='banner'>
    <div class="animation">
      <span id="f4"></span>
      <span id="f3"></span>
      <span id="f2"></span>
      <span id="f1"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Silly Webpage Banner</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="background-color:white;">
    Content
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbmx9x67/11/)

I've had to add height, width, top to the animation class just be able to see the image. If I exclude z-index, the content DIV sinks a layer. I'd really like it to respect background-size and background-position, but I can't figure out why it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going for something more like this? Where the background animation stuff is all contained within a banner div with a set width/height?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner h1 {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position banner title */
  top:1rem;
  left:1rem;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#main {
  position: relative;
}
.animation div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  background-size: cover cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
#f1 {
  animation-delay: -0s;
  background-image: url('https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/white-wallpaper-14.jpg');
}
#f2 {
  animation-delay: -10s;
  background-image: url('http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/White-Background-Wallpapers-3D-Ball.jpg');
}
#f3 {
  animation-delay: -20s;
  background-image: url('http://dlc.middcreate.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/quality-photo-for-desktop-white-bubbles-widescreen-picture-and-image-background-wallpaper-with-high-resolution.jpg');
}
#f4 {
  animation-delay: -30s;
  background-image: url('http://hdpic.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Pattern-Black-and-White-Amazing-Background-Cool-Background.jpg');
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>
  <div id='banner'>
    <div class="animation">
      <div id="f4"></div>
      <div id="f3"></div>
      <div id="f2"></div>
      <div id="f1"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>Silly Webpage Banner</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="title">
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:white;">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Woo-Hoo! Nailed it! I only changed `height: 4rem` to `height: auto` so it responses correctly when the banner title wraps. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

As said in [MDN's position reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor
>   (non-static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial
>   container is used.

Therefore your background div is out of the flow being placed on a higher layer thus hiding your content elements: that's why you need the `z-index` rule.

Finally, as your `absolute` positioned element does not affects or is affected by its parent, you'll have to define explicitly its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda wondering what you are trying to achieve here though, could try explaining a little?

```
.animation {
     height: any_height;
     position: relative;
     width: any_width;
}
```

I think that might help, if it answers the question.